# why does so many javascript libraries are loaded along with my website?

Tags: jquery, javascript, jquery-ui

I'm developing my website as a plugin. I'm loading all required javascript css and html files inside Plugin. But when look at the Network section in Developer tools, it showed me a lot of libraries from wordpress core are added along with my website, though i'm loading only Jquery from the core. 
Below libraries(not required for my plugin) are loaded in the background.

jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 
wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.8.2
core.min.js?ver=1.11.4
widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4
position.min.js?ver=1.11.4
menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4
wp-a11y.min.js?ver=4.8.2

How do I go about that?

Comment: They are, well, part of core admin interface? :) Are they _a problem_ really?

Comment: They are not part of admin interface. I believe it comes along with Twenty seventeen Theme. But i don't want to happen this, since i'm not including any theme content in my page. I have my own front page.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly are you doing and which context are you seeing the scripts in? I suspect "website as a plugin" has something to do with it, doesn't sound like typical operation.

Comment: What my plugin doing is,
1. Remove all theme contents like menu, widgets etc(create a blank page)
2. Load my custom html, CSS and javascript files.